# 2008 CALS for 2003 Term Server

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, terminal-server, licensing, cal

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can you help me with my software licensing question?](https://serverfault.com/questions/215405/can-you-help-me-with-my-software-licensing-question)

When installing 2008 CALs on a 2008 licensing server for a 2003 Terminal Server should I install them as 08s or 03s? Also is there anything else I need to do besides changing the group policy setting to point to the new licensing server? Does the licensing server have to be a domain controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The confusion that led to this question is that User CALs aren't tracked in 03. So I installed the 08 CAls as 08s, pointed to the new licensing server and it seems to be working fine. The licensing server is a domain controller, but I don't believe it has to be.

Comment: You are correct, I does not have to be.

Answer (score 0):

When I did this for a client a couple years back, I called MS to downgrade my licenses to 2003 from 2008. I just pointed the 2003 TS to the 2008 box that was my licensing server. I can't say that it does/doesn't have to be a domain controller, but that particular client's licensing box is a DC.

At the time, I got conflicting answers from inside MS if I could use 2008 TS CALs for 2003 server, downgrading them worked so that was what I went with.